# How to assign font in RDLC report at runtime?

Tags: c#, fonts, rdlc

anybody know how to assign new font at runtime in RDLC report?

I want to assign font to textbox.

thanks

Comment: You might change the fonts depending on the conditions,u will see a font dropdown, click expression and then set the fonts you want.

Comment: I want to set it dynamically.I am storing font in database and then retrieve and want to display in my rdlc report.do you know how can I do this ?